# How to get YouTube direct link with extension?

Tags: download, youtube

I know it is possible to get YouTube direct links nowadays online, like using clipconverter.cc or keepvid.com. This works well. But there is a little problem.

For example, if I try to grab direct link for this video `www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1-L58y2uf4`‎, of resolution 1080p HD, get a download link like:

`http://r9---sn-25g7sne7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&ip=2001:41d0:8:1f2b:3a0e:6049:6b4f:92e9&expire=1378905654&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&ipbits=48&upn=BgsjQ8lS424&cp=U0hWTVlLU19KTkNONl9RRVdHOkZIZ0diYTFXLWRJ&key=yt1&id=5b5f8be7ccb6b9fe&mt=1378881529&ratebypass=yes&itag=37&sver=3&mv=m&fexp=903309,919391,910207,914071,916612,924606,929117,929121,929906,929907,929922,929127,929129,929131,929930,936403,925726,936310,925720,925722,925718,925714,929917,906945,929933,920302,906842,913428,920605,919811,913563,919373,930803,908536,938701,931924,936308,909549,900816,912711,904494,904497,939903,900375,900382,934507,907231,936312,906001&ms=au&signature=1DDD3BB4A46816E27075ADF13C84B810AD1DF72D.C9B4290CE7F0806A3174E65DE3920F3AFDB06833&title=Kilimanjaro+-+ROBOT+%282010%29+%2AHD%2A+1080p+%2ABluRay%2A+Music+Video`

This works well with browsers, and one can download using this link. But the problem is, the URL has no filename and extension. When I try to download this video to my **[Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/)** using the option "upload from web", it says invalid file link. So how can get 1080p HD `.mp4` link for this video and thus can store it into my MediaFire?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if Mediafire isn't capable of handling those links then there's nothing you can do about it. That doesn't mean that there's no solution. The obvious one would be to download the file and upload it manually to Mediafire. You could also contact MediaFire and ask to add support for these kind of links.

Since that's probably not what you want, you could also use services that download the video for you onto their servers and provide you with a new, Mediafire-friendly link. There are plenty of those. Just google for them. Usually, RapidLeech-based servers support this feature.

Oh and cool video :)